# Unable to boot unexpected NMI at 0012:7AA3

Tags: boot, ibm, blade-server, bladecenter

I have an old IBM blade built in 2005. It is the HS20 blade.

Currently, the boot screen of the blade is reporting a `NMI fault at 0012:7AA3`.

The blade then fails at booting and restarts only to fail again and restart again.

I have attempted to reset the connections by pulling the blade out and placing it back in. I have also attempted to pull out the harddrives and I am receiving the same error.

I was wondering if anyone here knows what this error is and if there is a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have and NMI fault, you have a dead blade. NMI stands for Non-Maskable Interrupt. It's a form of hardware interrupt that is considered critical to the basic operation of the system as a whole, so it can't ever be ignored or fail.

NMI failures are fatal. That this blade has an NMI problem is not surprising: it's old enough to be garbage now, but not old enough to be cool.